# "Hot spot inv." in JProfiler

Tags: java, jprofiler

Using JProfiler to profile an application running on Oracle IAS, going into JEE & Probes -> JDBC -> Hot Spots, under the 'Unknown' tree an item called 'Hot spot inv. without CPU recording" shows as using 85% of the applications CPU time, but I can't find anything out about what this 'Hot Spot Inv.' item is.

### Edit;

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You got to give more info than that. Probably a screenshot would do (with package names erased if you wish)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"hot spot inv." stands for "hot spot invocations". This just means how often the hot spot has been called along the selected path.

Back traces are only available when CPU recording is active. The fact that you have some back traces and a large "without CPU recording" node means that you have started CPU recording after JDBC probe recording. To avoid this, start CPU recording before JDBC probe recording.

To learn more about hot spots and back traces, see [this help topic](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/helptopics/cpu/hotspotsAndFilters.html).